# How to run `x` command within a < action in the perl debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I'd like to get a semicomplex structure to be output before displaying the prompt in the debugger.  The best way to display it is to use the `x` command, but the command isn't available under that name or perhaps it's not in scope.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the documentation for `< [command]` in [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#%3C-%5B-command-%5D):

> **< [ command ]**
>
> Set an action (Perl command) to happen before every debugger prompt.

`x` is not a Perl command. You want `{ [command]`:

> **{ [ command ]**
>
> Set an action (debugger command) to happen before every debugger prompt.

For example:

```
$ perl -de'$foo = { foo => "bar" };
           print $foo'

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   $foo = { foo => "bar" };
  DB<1> { x $foo
  DB<2> n
main::(-e:2):   print $foo
auto(-1)  DB<2> x $foo
0  HASH(0x22af2c8)
   'foo' => 'bar'
```

Alternatively, use your favorite dumper module (e.g. [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper), [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer)):

```
$ perl -de'$foo = { foo => "bar" };
           print $foo'

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   $foo = { foo => "bar" };
  DB<1> use Data::Dumper

  DB<2> < print Dumper $foo
  DB<3> n
main::(-e:2):   print $foo
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => 'bar'
        };
```